# Create cookie if it's empty or delete and choose another button

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to simple reaction buttons like on facebook.I'm new to javascript but also know actionscript.So I'm not stranger exactly.I have 6 buttons in code.I need a click limit 2 buttons.Player can click only 2 diffrent buttons.Also the player can change his buttons any time if click twice same button then cookie will be delete and his can choose another one.How I can doing this ?

I created that with I learn until now.

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>

</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="multicookie()">Cookie Create</button>
    <button onclick="multicookie2()">Cookie Create2</button>
    <button onclick="multicookie3()">Cookie Create3</button>
    <button onclick="multicookie4()">Cookie Create4</button>
    <button onclick="multicookie5()">Cookie Create5</button>
    <button onclick="multicookie6()">Cookie Create6</button>
    <button onclick="multicookieRead()">Read cookies</button>
    <script>
        function multicookie() {           
            cookieCreater("cookie1", "Sad", 4);
/*miyok anima nicip o nerev iske anab*/
        }
        function multicookie2() {           

 cookieCreater("cookie2", "Angry", 4);

        }
        function multicookie3() {           

 cookieCreater("cookie3", "Smile", 4);

        }

        function multicookie4() {           

 cookieCreater("cookie4", "Cool", 4);

        }

        function multicookie5() {           

 cookieCreater("cookie5", "Kiss", 4);

        }
        function multicookie6() {           

 cookieCreater("cookie6", "Neutral", 4);

        }
        function multicookieRead() {
            alert(readCookie("cookie1"));
 alert(readCookie("cookie2"));
 alert(readCookie("cookie3"));
  alert(readCookie("cookie4"));
   alert(readCookie("cookie5"));
    alert(readCookie("cookie6"));
        }

        function cookieCreater(name, value, gecerlilikSuresi) {
            var t = new Date();
            t.setTime(t.getTime() + (gecerlilikSuresi * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
            var expirationdate = "expires=" + t.toUTCString();
            document.cookie = name + "=" + value + "; " + expirationdate + "; path=/";
        }
        function readCookie(name) {
            var name = name + "=";
            var cookiler = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < cookiler.length; i++) {
                var c = cookiler[i];
                while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
                    c = c.substring(1);
                }
                if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                    return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
                }
            }
            return "";
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are facing in your implementation?

Comment: I tried delete cookie to click the button twice but it's not.Then I removed the function and I'm looking for another way now.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but, you do *not* have a cookie overwrite function declared?

Comment: yes, it would have been better to leave the non-working code with a question why it didn't work, as Stack Overflow is a Q&A site, not a free coding service ;)

Comment: No I haven't yet.So I asking how ?

Comment: I create topic because I'm stack.

Answer (score 2):

i did it because it was actually pretty simple, because you had a readCookie function already. All i did was to test it the cookie existed, and influenced the expiration accordingly, to create or destroy it:

**NOTE**: created a snippet because it was easier for formatting, but it won't work due to snippet restrictions

```html
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>

</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="multicookie()">Cookie Create</button>
    <button onclick="multicookie2()">Cookie Create2</button>
    <button onclick="multicookie3()">Cookie Create3</button>
    <button onclick="multicookie4()">Cookie Create4</button>
    <button onclick="multicookie5()">Cookie Create5</button>
    <button onclick="multicookie6()">Cookie Create6</button>
    <button onclick="multicookieRead()">Read cookies</button>
    <script>
        function multicookie() {           
            cookieCreater("cookie1", "Sad", 4);
        }
        function multicookie2() {           
            cookieCreater("cookie2", "Angry", 4);
        }
        function multicookie3() {           
            cookieCreater("cookie3", "Smile", 4);
        }
        function multicookie4() {           
            cookieCreater("cookie4", "Cool", 4);
        }
        function multicookie5() {           
            cookieCreater("cookie5", "Kiss", 4);
        }
        function multicookie6() {           
            cookieCreater("cookie6", "Neutral", 4);
        }
        function multicookieRead() {
            alert(readCookie("cookie1"));
            alert(readCookie("cookie2"));
            alert(readCookie("cookie3"));
            alert(readCookie("cookie4"));
            alert(readCookie("cookie5"));
            alert(readCookie("cookie6"));
        }

        function cookieCreater(name, value, gecerlilikSuresi) {
            var t = new Date(), expirationdate;
            if(readCookie(name) === ""){
                t.setTime(t.getTime() + (gecerlilikSuresi * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
                expirationdate = "expires=" + t.toUTCString();
            }else{
                expirationdate = "expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT";
            }
            document.cookie = name + "=" + value + "; " + expirationdate + "; path=/";
        }
        function readCookie(name) {
            var name = name + "=";
            var cookiler = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < cookiler.length; i++) {
                var c = cookiler[i];
                while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
                    c = c.substring(1);
                }
                if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                    return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
                }
            }
            return "";
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you.But it's not what I'm looking for.I mean user can change his choose.Can you check the example link on my first post ?

Comment: The answer solves the specific problem you ask in the question, but as I said, i am quite a busy man and cannot write all of your code. What you need to do now is to count your "reaction" cookies and test your maximum value to prevent action or not. Man, i actually don't even know what you want to do if maximum is reached (disable buttons? an alert?)

Comment: I want to use an alert.But is not important now.Do ı need to use something like "if(cookies.length<2){" ?

Comment: that wouldn't be safe, take in consideration that you may want to add other javascript cookies. Better to add a code that specifically looks for your 6 named cookies using your `readCookie` function and testing if response is empty string `""` just as i did.